# Why won't my electric furnace kick on unless the thermostat is set to 73?

Tags: hvac

I have an older, ill insulated mobile home. My house is obviously not 73 degrees, and my heater will not kick on. I set it to 73 and it finally came on, but then the furnace would not shut off. It blew all night and in to the morning, I had to shut it off by turning it to below 73.

We looked at the limit switches; one of which is not connected at all, and another is wired but not wired to the on/off switch (that looks like a miniature breaker box).

Comment: Sounds more like a thermostat problem than a furnace problem.

Comment: What is the make and model of the furnace and thermostat? Has this just started, or has it always been a problem? Were there any changes made to the system that may have caused this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Thermostats are trivial to replace.  Buy a replacement that works with your heating system.  Carefully remove the existing thermostat from the wall, label the wires as to what they are connected to before removing, and connect your new thermostat in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if you ever found the answer but thermostats have a range called span or deadband. This is normally programmable on electronic thermostats like +2-2 from the set point but can be set to +4-0 for example. The larger the span or dead band where the thermostat doesn't change the output the higher or lower the temp will be on the display.
With mechanical thermostats it varies and can be adjusted above or below but the span doesn't change just the calibration point.
Hopefully that helps.